# TypeScript: can't disable type definitions for one special library

Tags: typescript

**TypeScript Version:**  2.4.1

For example I want to consume a library from npm called `awesome-lib`. This library already ships with a TypeScript type definition but this one is outdated and buggy. The author of the library doesn't update this one.

I've tried to disable that type definition completely in my own `declarations.d.ts` file in my project:

```
declare module 'awesome-lib';
```

Unfortunately TypeScript reads **first** the type definition in the library and throws some errors. So it is not possible for me to disable / hide this library for my project.

Does anyone know how to disable type checking for **one** special library?

Comment: Delete their (outdated) definitions.

Comment: How do I do that? Locally in my node_modules directory? And what about CI systems, co-workers and so on?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you could try to use require instead of import:

```
/* tslint:disable:no-var-requires */
const awesomeLib: any = require("awesome-lib");
/* tslint:enable:no-var-requires */
```

the downside is you have no type checking nor intellisense.

Comment: This would help a little bit. But unfortunately not in my case. You can reproduce it very easily: create a new project and try to use Preact instead of React. Then add some libraries that depend on React => TypeScript fails because of wrong types in Preact.

Answer (score 0):

It may not be a real solution, but if the library is abandoned and broken, you could fork that library, modify its typings and use that in your project.

Comment: Unfortunately thats not exactly what I want. Especially if the package is well known and referenced from a lot of libraries at npmjs.com